# Template Alias with Default Value

Tags: c++, c++11, template-aliases

**Info**

I am trying to use a template alias to improve the readabilty of my code. Ideally I would like to the alias to have a default argument such that if I leave out the template it uses the default (exactly with template functions and template classes).

The code would look like

```
template<typename T = double>
struct mystruct {};

template<typename T = double> using myalias = mystruct<T>;

int main(void) {

    myalias MyStructWithDouble; // causes compilation error
    myalias<int> MyStructWithInt;

    return 0;
}
```

The compiler (g++ 4.7 in this case) is quite happy with the inclusion of the `= double` in the alias definition but it seems to then ignore this.

I tried something like "specializing" the alias as well but there the compiler baulked.

**Question**

Why does the compiler accept the default in the defintion if we are not allowed to use it? Secondly, is there a way of acheiveing this?

**Motivation**

This example is very simple but in my real code the alias would save a lot of typing (there are more than one template parameter)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Just like with class templates, you still need to supply an empty template argument list:

```
myalias<> MyStructWithDouble; // compiles
```

Comment: Could you elaborate why this is the case? If I were to create this directly from `mystruct` I can simply type `mystruct MyStructWithDouble;`?

Comment: @Dan: No you can't, at least not without a nonstandard compiler extension. For example, GCC says

`error: invalid use of template-name ‘mystruct’ without an argument list`

Comment: My mistake. Is there any reason for this? Can the compiler not tell that `myalias` means the same as `myalias<>`? And is there some way to "cheat" this behaviour from the compiler?

Comment: @Dan: I don't think so, unfortunately. It's probably for the same reason that you need to say `f()` when calling a no-argument function `f`: the name without the parentheses refers to the function itself. Similarly, the name of a template without a (possibly empty) parameter list refers to the template itself (so you can pass it as a template template parameter), whereas the name with the angle brackets denotes an instantiation of said template.

Comment: Nice analogy. That makes sense. It just means my code won't be as clean as I would like, oh well.